# Repeting a Math.random variable without getting the same result in three.js

Tags: random, three.js

Maybe a newbie question but i'd like to use a random variable several times in my code, but of course it reminds the same for all parameters using it. How could I fix it ?

Example :

```
var randomColor = [yellow, blue, green][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]

const cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, randomColor);
scene.add(cube1);

const cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, randomColor);
scene.add(cube2);
```

Those two cubes will have to same material (named randomColor) even if it is random.
Thank you in advance !

Comment: Make `randomColor` a function, thus it returns a random color when it's called. `var randomColor = function(){ return [yellow, blue, green][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)] }`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the same random color every time, you generate a new one by calling `getRandomColor()` as soon as you need it.

```js
const colors = ['yellow', 'blue', 'green']
function getRandomColor() {
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)
  return colors[index]
}

const cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, getRandomColor());
scene.add(cube1);

const cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, getRandomColor());
scene.add(cube2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, the previous answers are not working with three.js :/ :

```
let colors = ['0xff0000','0xf7c252','0xa0bbd0']

    const colour = new THREE.Color();
    colour.setHex(colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]);
    
    fond = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial({ color: colour });
    
    const cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, fond);
    scene.add(cube1);

    const cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, fond);
    scene.add(cube2);
```